# Convert an SVG to PNG without client side loading

Tags: javascript

I have introduced Content security policy in my web application, so need to avoid all 'data:' calls,
I need to convert an SVG to PNG without leaving a 'data:' call. Currently, it is called at

```
// set it as the source of the img element
img.src = image64;
```

I am attaching [jsfidde](https://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo5/h2L3gw88/) herewith which is my current implementation.
can this possible?

Comment: Are `blob://` URIs also blocked by your CSP? Actually that would be great to share which CSP you are facing exactly. And your current code is missing some important points (an absolute width for the svg and waiting for the img's onload event before drawing it) https://jsfiddle.net/aurdgj7c/

Comment: Sure, here it is `Content-Security-Policy "img-src 'self' https://www.facebook.com/ ; script-src 'self'... `

Comment: [edit] the question itself please

Comment: is that okay to allow `blob://`? my concerns are on XSS vulnerability.

Comment: 'blob://' is also blocked by my current CSP

Comment: XSS through `img-src`? And blob:// URI exposes to the same exact risks as data:// URI, but for `img-src` I'd say there is no real risk in allowing data:// URI and blob:// URIs. As I understand it, `img-src` is mainly to prevent pixel-tracking.

Comment: I referred in [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94993/is-including-the-data-scheme-in-your-content-security-policy-safe/95011) stack exchange question

Comment: Well you should probably refer to the most upvoted answer where they explain that the accepted one over-read the MDN's note which was not about `img-src`. Documents loaded in `<img>` are sandboxed and can't execute any script. You're safe.